# How to get all the action results related to a azure logic app run or execution at one shot?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rest-api

I have a azure logic app designed at my end with some many connectors and loops and conditions like Sending email,SQL update and other set of things.

The flow gets executed properly as per my requirement and provides me the end result.

Now what i want is to get all the steps or actions performed in a particular logic app run to be retrieved at one shot along with status. Let me explain my query by taking a small example of logic app:

Let assume there is a logic app 5 steps with Name as TestLogicAPP and it has  following actions or steps in it:

STEP 1: Flow is triggered when email is received : The connector used in OFfice365
STEP 2: After the flow is triggered first action is marking it as read: again connector used is Office365
STEP 3: Sending a reply to the sender: again connector used is Office365
STEP 4: Assume there is a  attachment coming in email, and Storing attachment name in a variable by declaring a variable Using inbuilt variable deceleration
STEP 5: Storing this attachment received in email into Azure File storage or file share: Used azure file storage connector

All these steps are executed in logic apps perfectly without any errors when you the run history.

What i want is to list all these actions/steps at one go with its status like

STEP1 name : Successful
STEP2 name : Successful
STEP3 name : Failed along with failed reason or message(assuming 3rd is failed from above given example)

Or

STEP1 name : Successful
STEP2 name : Successful
STEP3 name : Successful
STEP4 name : Successful
STEP5 name : Successful

For this When i searched web i got a a rest API provided by Microsoft that gives these details:

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs/{runName}/actions?api-version=2016-06-01

Above API Taken from below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowrunactions/list#code-try-0

But when executed it is not listing all the actions in a given logic app run. To be specific it is not listing below connector related actions:

1. Trigger action of logic app(office 365 connector)
2. Sending email (office 365 connector)
3. Uploading attachment file in email to Azure file share or file storage

Note sure why? Is it a bug in Microsoft Logic APP REST API or is it built to display or omit these type of steps or actions purposefully?

Or Is there any other way to get the desired result explained above?

Please help me regarding this issue or query.

Searched web and found the Logic app related rest API from below link as described above.

**Expected Result:** Get all actions or step results of a logic app run including the trigger action

**Actual Result:** Getting only few actions/steps result few are getting omitted from the rest api  result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I know how did you call the rest api ? I test it and get the expected results, post the steps as below for your reference:

1. I created a logic app in my azure portal(shown as screenshot below)
   [image]
2. Send an email to the email address to trigger this logic app.
3. In the run history of my logic app, it shows as below screenshot. The action "Mark as read or unread" is failed and the last action was skipped.
   [image]
4. Then I went to the page of the rest api you provided: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowrunactions/list and click "Try it". Input all of the params which are required such as "resourceGroupName", "workflowName" and "runName".
   [image]
5. After click "Run", the result show as below:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "inputsLink": {
          "uri": "xxxxxxxxx",
          "contentVersion": "xxxxxxx",
          "contentSize": 377,
          "contentHash": {
            "algorithm": "md5",
            "value": "xxxxxx"
          }
        },
        "outputsLink": {
          "uri": "xxxxxxxx",
          "contentVersion": "xxxxxxx",
          "contentSize": 766,
          "contentHash": {
            "algorithm": "md5",
            "value": "xxxxxxx"
          }
        },
        "startTime": "2019-10-28T06:17:56.8609023Z",
        "endTime": "2019-10-28T06:17:56.9044006Z",
        "correlation": {
          "actionTrackingId": "xxxxxxx",
          "clientTrackingId": "xxxxxxx"
        },
        "status": "Failed",
        "code": "BadRequest"
      },
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/huryTest/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/hurylogicsteps/runs/xxxxxx/actions/Mark_as_read_or_unread_(V2)",
      "name": "Mark_as_read_or_unread_(V2)",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/actions"
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "startTime": "2019-10-28T06:17:56.9859119Z",
        "endTime": "2019-10-28T06:17:56.9977121Z",
        "correlation": {
          "actionTrackingId": "xxxxxx",
          "clientTrackingId": "xxxxxx"
        },
        "status": "Skipped",
        "code": "ActionSkipped",
        "error": {
          "code": "ActionConditionFailed",
          "message": "The execution of template action 'Send_an_email_(V2)' is skipped: the 'runAfter' condition for action 'Mark_as_read_or_unread_(V2)' is not satisfied. Expected status values 'Succeeded' and actual value 'Failed'."
        }
      },
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/huryTest/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/hurylogicsteps/runs/xxxxxx/actions/Send_an_email_(V2)",
      "name": "Send_an_email_(V2)",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/runs/actions"
    }
  ]
}
```

We can see there are two actions under "values" in the response body in json type. The status of "Mark_as_read_or_unread_(V2)" is "Failed" and the status of "Send_an_email_(V2)" is "Skipped". Although they failed or skipped, but both of them are shown in the result of this rest api.(in your question, you said "Sending email" is not list in the result)

By the way:
As far as I know, this api just shows the actions, but the trigger is not an action. So the trigger will not show in the result of this api.

Apart from this, if we don't use the rest api, we can also see all of the status of the action in azure portal by "Runs history" --> "Run Details"

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~

Comment: I had tested the REST API exactly as you have explained using the same Try It option and providing the WorkFlow name,Resource group and RUN id the portal but for me few actions as i have listed above are not displayed.  However, in my original logic app there are more than 55 Steps that gets executed ina  successful flow but as i said few things are not displayed even though the history shows as successful with a tick in right side top corner of that action. I am not sure why though that is why i posted this query. Anyways thanks for all the help and time you have done till now.

Comment: Hi @ChaitanyaNG, as in my side the rest api works fine, I suggest you to raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). The support team can see the background data of your logic app and help you on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help till now. i should raise a ticket.